# Unable To Access Hidden Values In .CS file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am stuckup with little problem

I have the form contains 3 hidden controls, I am sending values through jquery. Upto this its working fine while I keep alert.

I am using FormCollection and try to retrieve those hidden values in .cs file but I am unable to retireve those values. When I keep break point on FormCollections its showing all the hidden control names including key numbers.

View:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan ="2">
        @Html.Hidden("hdnddlid")
        @Html.Hidden("hdnrblMale")
        @Html.Hidden("hdnrblFeMale")
    </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name='Gender']").change(function () {
            if ($("input[name='Gender']:checked").val() == '1') {
                hdnrblMale = "Male";
            }
            else if ($("input[name='Gender']:checked").val() == '0') {
                hdnrblFeMale = "FeMale";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code in .cs file

```
public static void InsertPersonalDetails(PersonalDetails modelPersonal, FormCollection frmHdnValues)
{
    try
    {
        PersonalDbContext db = new PersonalDbContext();

        string Male = frmHdnValues["hdnrblMale"].ToString();
        string Female = frmHdnValues["hdnrblFeMale"].ToString();

        db.Entry(modelPersonal).State = EntityState.Added;
        //pDetails.Add(Objpd);
        db.SaveChanges();
        // return pDetails;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your emitted html (DOM) look like?

Comment: Do you have all this wrapped inside of a form?  Have you used a web dev tool like Firebug or Chrome Developer tools to make sure your value is getting set on the hidden inputs?

Comment: @Shane - Yes Shane, I used all the things you said above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something or doesn't your jQuery need to be:

```
$("input[name='hdnrblMale']").val("Male");
```

instead of

```
hdnrblMale = "Male";
```

also make sure that the fields are within a form being submitted.

I use a combination of

- **Visual Studio**: break points, step through code, immediate window
- **Chrome**: break points in JS, JS immediate window, inspect element
- **fiddler2**: see that is actually being sent to and from the server (note may beet to use localhost. instead of localhost for traffic to
  show up in fiddler - e.g. localhost.:69230 instead of
  localhost:69230)

to debug this type of thing.. that way you should have visibility of all parts of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try Input type hidden and in controller write `request.form["FieldName"]`. this is working    in my case